# How do I create a new file in a folder owned by root? Specifically, I want to add a file to /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d

Tags: files, directory, root

I want to add a new file to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` as seen at the bottom of [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mouse_acceleration) page, but I can't as it's owned by root user. How to?

EDIT: I managed it using the information on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425192/how-do-i-unprotect-a-file-which-is-owned-by-root) page:

Comment: Are you looking for a "command line" answer, or are you a Point-Click-and-Wonder-What-Happened type of questioner>?

Comment: I'd like a command line answer I guess. Sorry if it's a stupid question, just got Ubuntu yesterday coming from windows

Answer (score 2):

First, create the file, using the editor of your choice. Store it in a user directory, something in or under `$HOME` Check it to be sure it says what you think it says, and does what you want. Then, and only then:

```
sudo cp yourfile /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-mouse-acceleration.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Become root before creating the file or run the editor you're going to use to create the file as root.

For example:

```
sudo -i gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-mouse-acceleration.conf
#paste in the file content, save it, you're done.
```

Comment: This is what I tried first! But when I try to save it it says "Could not find the file “/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-mouse-acceleration.conf”. Please check that you typed the location correctly and try again."

Comment: Sorry, updated, I forgot, ubuntu uses a different location

Comment: Thanks, I should have realized to try that again when I learnt that Ubuntu used a different path :) ... and even more should have used the correct path in my post -_-

Comment: Why the edit, A.B.?

Comment: @Stephen sorry for the edit without a comment. But you shouldn't use `sudo` to start a GUI, it's OK, to start an application with a CLI. Use `sudo -i`, `pkexec` or `gksudo` for applications with a GUI like Gedit and so on.

Comment: If you write me a message, use `@A.B.`. I don't get a ping without the `@`

Comment: @A.B. So the potential side effect of not doing "-i" and inheriting root's environment is that you get temp files created in your home that could prevent the correct operation of programs running as your user?  Are there other side effects?

Comment: Anywhere on Ask Ubuntu is a very long discussion for this.

Answer (score -1):

if you simply want to change owner of a file you can use `chown` command
as [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-use-chmod-and-chown-command/) it is told the usage is simply `sudo chmod root filename`